# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS...no idea what to do

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

here is my query

```
DECLARE @CharID INT;

SELECT @CharID = (SELECT TOP 1 CharID,
                               Count(*) AS Kills
                  FROM   eBot.dbo._Uniques
                  WHERE  UniqueID IN(SELECT ID
                                     FROM   OVERLIMIT_SHARD_NOW .dbo._RefObjCommon
                                     WHERE  CodeName128 LIKE '%MOB_%_%%')
                  GROUP  BY CharID
                  ORDER  BY Kills DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler and possibily more efficient way would be ...

```
DECLARE @CharID INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @CharID = CharID
FROM   eBot.dbo._Uniques
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM  OVERLIMIT_SHARD_NOW .dbo._RefObjCommon t
               WHERE t.CodeName128 LIKE '%MOB_%_%%'
                 AND dbo._Uniques.UniqueID = t.ID)
GROUP BY CharID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting more than one column in `subquery` (ie) `CharID  and COUNT(*)` which is not allowed in `sql server`

If am not wrong you need to remove `Count(*)` from `subquery` and keep the 
`Count(*)` directly in `order by`

```
DECLARE @CharID INT;

SELECT @CharID = (SELECT TOP 1 CharID
                  FROM   eBot.dbo._Uniques
                  WHERE  UniqueID IN(SELECT ID
                                     FROM   OVERLIMIT_SHARD_NOW .dbo._RefObjCommon
                                     WHERE  CodeName128 LIKE '%MOB_%_%%')
                  GROUP  BY CharID
                  ORDER  BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```